# Need to create a POST Facebook check in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-checkins

I'd like to create a link or button on my website for a user to click on, that will check them into a place on Facebook.

I'd like to have the code be flexible so I may change the place name within the code (and re-use the code for checkins at different locations within the site)

I tried to create this via the Graph API using POST with LOCATION attached but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you show the text of the call you made?  What was the error message you received.  Using the Graph API requires the user to authorize your app for you to Post on their behalf.  Have you created a process to do that and then save the associated Security Token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/tagged_places/#publish you need to publish a Post via `/{user-id}/feed`

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed/#publish You need a specific `place_id` to do this, and the `read_stream` permission in the User Access Token.